# Access block variable from method

Tags: ruby

I have a Websocket server (using Rubame), and it handles server connections in block form:

```
server.run do |client|
    # ...
end
```

The client sends a message (i.e. `ping;end`) to the server, then the server sends a message back (i.e. `pong;end`).

Instead of having my react-to-message code inside the block, creating a huge, ugly mess, I want to have it in a function:

```
def react(msg)
    # ...
end
server.run do |client|
    client.onmessage do |mess|
        react(mess)
    end
end
```

To send a message back to the client, I need to access the `client` variable passed to the `server.run` block, and it appears to not be accessible from within the method.

Is there a way to access the variables of a block from within a method which was called inside the block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `client` along to your method:

```
def react(client, msg)
  # ...
end

server.run do |client|
  client.onmessage do |mess|
    react(client, mess)
  end
end
```